# JAR libraries to TomCat

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

My servlet application uses `JavaMail API and Java Activation Framework (JAF)`. I do development in `IntelliJ` IDE. `TomCat` runs on the same local `Windows` machine. When I try to run my Servlet from `IntelliJ` I have error related to fact `TomCat` not finds mentioned libraries. What is the right place to store libraries for `TomCat`? Is it possible ask `IntelliJ` to place required libraries to `TomCat` ?

Comment: I'd put them in the the server /lib.  Don't do it through IntelliJ; add it manually.

Comment: Only Java EE server libraries like mail, etc.  Not application specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

Put the jar files in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. If there isn't one, create one manually.

This way the jar files are added to the war file that gets created when you build your artifact, and tomcat knows where to find those jars at runtime.